# understanding make.config file

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to build a package for installing on ubuntu. There is a make.config file which has references to required libraries and files for the installation. I need to change some of the lines and as a prerequisite I need to understand the make.config file:

```
CBLASLIB_LIN=-L/home/johanstr/apps/ATLAS3.8.3/bamako_build/lib/ -latlas
```

and

```
LDFLAGS_LIN= $(CBLASLIB_LIN) -lstdc++ -pthread -lpthread
```

and

```
OPTIMISE_LIN= -O3 -pipe -fexpensive-optimizations -ffast-math -funroll-all-loops -fprefetch-loop-arrays
```

I don't know what these parameters and variables mean.

Comment: Your question is probably too generally worded for a site like SO.  Asking specific questions about specific flags is much better than pasting a lot of content and asking for people to explain it all, which may or may not end up answering your questions.

Answer (score 1):

From a make point of view, three different variables are set.

These are flags for your compiler. 
The first one specifies path and name of the atlas Library, this is probably one you need to modify

The second adds some additional libraries to the linker flags.
The third one sets various optimization options.

Comment: Specifically what is the relation between -latlas and the path provided in the same line?

Comment: Just a note: if your question is not answered you shouldn't check it as answered.  Once a question is checked as answered most people who could answer it will not read it.

Comment: I didn't notice that.